# Browserstack with Playwright not logging all test runs / restarting browser

Tags: playwright, browserstack, browserstack-app-automate

I'm writing Playwright tests integrated with the Browserstack Automate dashboard. I have encountered a situation where if run e.g. 5 tests in a file, they will all run locally in Playwright and all results will be displayed in terminal, but the Browserstack Dashboard will always only be updated with results of 2 tests (the default number of workers for each test run is 2).

However, if I manually open (`const browser = await chromium.launch(); const page = await browser.newPage();`) and close the browser in each test, the Browserstack dashboard correctly logs all test runs.

This works:

```
test('test1', async ({ }) => {
  test.setTimeout(240000)
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    //test code here
    await page.evaluate(_ => {}, `browserstack_executor: ${JSON.stringify({action: 'setSessionStatus',arguments: {name: '', status: 'passed',reason: ''}})}`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    await page.evaluate(_ => {}, `browserstack_executor: ${JSON.stringify({action: 'setSessionStatus',arguments: {name: '', status: 'failed',reason: ''}})}`);

  }  
  browser.close()

});

....
```

Given that opening and closing the browser for each individual test seems to make Browserstack log them correctly, I'm trying to write a beforeEach and afterEach hook to do this. However, this doesn't work:

```
test.beforeEach(async ({  }) => {
    const browser = await chromium.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(`${url}`);
  });

test('test1', async ({ page }) => {
  test.setTimeout(240000)
  try {
    //test code here
    await page.evaluate(_ => {}, `browserstack_executor: ${JSON.stringify({action: 'setSessionStatus',arguments: {name: '', status: 'passed',reason: ''}})}`);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    await page.evaluate(_ => {}, `browserstack_executor: ${JSON.stringify({action: 'setSessionStatus',arguments: {name: '', status: 'failed',reason: ''}})}`);

  }  


});

....

test.afterEach(async ({ browser }) => {
    browser.close()
  });
```

The before/afterEach hooks keep resulting in error messages about the browser being abruptly closed. Is there a better way to open/close browsers for each test? I know that other testing frameworks have a config setting for restarting the browser. Or maybe there is another way to make the test results appear in the Browserstack Automate dashboard?

Comment: Hi,
1. Could you please try to add await browser.close(); in the afterEach block?
2. Please check out BrowserStack's PlayWright sample repo for example code, here: https://github.com/browserstack/playwright-browserstack/tree/main

Comment: @AshwaniPathak thanks for your comment. 1, I added `await` to the `browser.close()` in my afterEach hook posted above and I still have the same result as before ('Browser has been closed' error in Playwright/'Abrupt close' in Browserstack). 2. I cloned the example repo and get an error when trying to run it (' require(...).addTestCommand is not a function'), but looking through the code, it seems like it doesn't make use of before/afterEach hooks.